# c++ can't instantiate a subclass due to parent protected constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is the code i have trouble understanding:

```
class A 
{ 
protected: 
   int _i; 
   A () : _i(0) { } 
   ~A () { } 
}; 

class B: public A 
{ 
public: 
   A *_pa; 
   B()  : A(), _pa(new A())
   { } 

  ~B () 
   { 
      delete _pa; 
   } 
}; 

int main () 
{ 
   A a; //ERROR
   B b; //ERROR
}
```

When trying to instantiate a class of type `A` i get an error because it's constructor is protected. But why can't I instantiate a class of type `B`? The class has access to protected members of `A` (including the ctor) so it should compile.

Comment: Also paste the error and the line where it's appearing.

Comment: Why do you want to have a member class pointer _and_ an inherited class of type `A`?

Comment: @TylerJandreau obviously, he is just testing protected constructors...

Comment: @AndréPuel Don't obviously me, guy. I just wanted some clarity.

Comment: @TylerJandreau just testing Tyler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is located the `new A` inside the `B` constructor, not on the call to super's constructor.

Let me explain you how `protected` works. When you have a class `B`, which is subclass of `A` it does not have access to protected elements of `A`, it has access to protected elements of `A` when dealing with a `B` reference.

To show my point:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void do_it(A* a) {
        std::cout << a->a << std::endl; //ERROR
    }
    void do_it(B* a) {
        std::cout << a->a << std::endl; //VALID CODE
    }
};
```

I guess the reason behind this behavior is that if you have a third class `C` which also access `A` protected members, probably it is not a good idea that someone else change these protected values.

Comment: hmm so it's because `new` is in the global scope

Comment: @Tom No, `new` is in B context, which does not have access to A without using B reference. `new A` is a pointer to A, not to B, so you cannot access it's constructor...

Answer (score 4):

Deriving from A only gives you access to protected members that you access through "this" or through another B. B doesn't have access to _pa's protected members.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in **main**. In there you can not instantiate A, because its constructor is protected.

Additionally you are not able to call the constructor of `_pa` in the constructor of B.

Comment: I know but i can't instantiate B neither. I understand why A won't work

Answer (score -1):

At the constructor of `B`, `A` constructor is called. Because of `A`'s constructor is protected, calling `A`'s constructor at the `B`'s constructor gives error. Also in the protected scope of `A`, there is destructor. When `B`'s destructor is invoked, its base class (`A`)'s destructor is called also. Because `A`'s destructor is protected, there occurs another error also. If you take the out the `A`'s constructor off from the `B`'s constructor, there still shows error. But you can get rid of the errors after making public the `A`'s destructor.

```
public:
   ~A () { }
```

This deduction made by inspection the errors given by codeblocks, but seems wrong. Removing _pa(new A()) is the exact solution.@AndréPuel 's answer more correct.